# Unable to detect the URI-scheme of "urltest" error Python

Tags: python, url

I am getting the error when trying to open a url I obtained from reading data from a .txt file in python using match.group(). This is my code below for where the error comes up. Any help as too how this can be corrected would be very much appreciated.

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            match = re.search("(?P<url>https?://docs.google.com/file[^\s]+)", line)
            if match is not None:
                urltest = match.group() 
print urltest

    print "[*] Opening Map in the web browser..."
    kml_url = "urltest"

    try:
        webbrowser.get().open_new_tab(kml_url)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the uri you are trying to match and how you want to parse it? You should at least use escape characters for the / and convert them to \/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided what you are trying to parse I can only guess but this should pretty much work for your url:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search('(?P<url>https:\/\/docs.google.com\/file[a-zA-z0-9-]*)', 'https://docs.google.com/fileCharWithnumbers123')
>>> match.group("url")
'https://docs.google.com/fileCharWithnumbers123'
```